# gridview button

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I apologize if this is a real simple question, but I can't find anyone else to ask. I have a gridview with a button column.  I'm trying to use the button column to send a filename to another page.  I pulled this code off of another solution here, but I get an error: "Does not contain a definition for 'Item'" on this line: ListViewDataItem item = (ListViewDataItem)e.**Item**; and I have no idea which Using-namespace (is that what they are called?) to use.

```
protected void gvFiles_RowCommand(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.CommandName == "edit")
    {
        ListViewDataItem item = (ListViewDataItem)e.Item;

        int index = item.DataItemIndex;
        string fileID = ((ListView)sender).DataKeys[index]["fileID"].ToString();

        Response.Redirect("irMain.aspx?@filename=" + fileID);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you are dealing with  a gridView not a ListView, then the code should be

```
protected void gvFiles_RowCommand(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs e) 
{ 

    if (e.CommandName == "edit") 
    { 
        int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
        string fileID = ((GridView)sender).DataKeys[index]["fileID"].ToString(); 
        Response.Redirect("irMain.aspx?@filename=" + fileID); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: I don't suppose you could tell me why a gridview would fire the rowediting event, when I just want to press the button and have it run the RowCommand event?

Comment: I'm not an expert in ASP.NET, so can't really help but look if you have the `AutoGenerateEditButton="True"`. [See MSDN refs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowediting) for `RowEditing` and for [RowCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcommand)